# java class A extends class B, and method override

Tags: java, class, overriding, extends

```
public class A {
   protected ClassX a;
   public void foo() {
       operations on a;
   }
}

public class B extends A {
   private ClassY b; // ClassY extends ClassX
   @Override
   public void foo() {
       //wanna the exact same operation as A.foo(), but on b;
   } 
}
```

Sorry for such a not clear title.
My question is: in class B, when I call foo(), and I want the exact same operation as class A have on a. How do I achive that and without duplicate the same code from A?
If i leave out foo() in class B, would it work?
Or whats happening when I call super.foo() in foo();

Comment: `Do you mean that my class hierarchy is not well defined?`  Alex, I deleted my answer. I didn't read the question clearly. Please disregard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since ClassY extends ClassX, then you can remove `private ClassY b` from class B. Then you can just set your instance of ClassX to the `a` instance variable. This allows `foo()` to be inherited in class B, but still use the same logic and instance variable.

```
public class A {
    protected ClassX a

    public void foo() {
        // operations on a;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    // do something to set an instance of ClassY to a; for example...
    public void setClassY(ClassY b){
        this.a = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't have any effect on `b`.

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild, The OP said it was.

Comment: @JeremyHeiler: would it be super.a = this.b?

Comment: @Alex, No. Since B extends A, then any instance of B can refer to its own `a` as `this.a`. Also, by saying `this.b` you are implying that there is a `b` instance variable, which there is not in my example.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `ClassX` and `ClassY` would have a common interface (if they have the same methods you want to call on earch, at least).  Have you considered making `foo()` take in an object of the type of the common interface?

```
public class A {
   private ClassX a;
   protected void foo(ClassXAndClassYInheritMe anObject) {
       operations on anObject;
   }

   public void foo() {
       foo(a);
   }
}

public class B {
   private ClassY b;
   @Override
   public void foo() {
       foo(b);
   }
}
```

Comment: I think ClassXAndClassYInheritMe can be just ClassX because ClassY extends ClassX

Comment: @hoge1e3 You are correct.  That is something that I didn't see in the original question.  Either way, it still stands that this would be a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

Don't define the foo() method in B if you want the same operation as that in A. If you want a different operation as A, override the foo() method in B. If you want to extend the foo() method in B so that it first does the operation in A and then in B, then call super.foo() at the top of the method; if you want the operation in A to come after the one in B, then call super.foo() at the end of the method foo().

Answer (score 0):

You can do `super.foo()` inside your overrided method.

Comment: would this have the operation on a?

Comment: Sure, when you  call super, it first runs the method of your superclass, in this case class A method foo.